# Github page returns a 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, github-pages

Github page - https://kaushalvyas010.github.io/me/

Github repo - https://github.com/kaushalvyas010/me.git

**Expected behaviour**: Github page opens fine

**Actual behaviour**: I don't know why but the page returns a 404.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved, on its own. Probably an issue with github's synch with the cloud.